# Does creating a folder in default maven directory structure offered by eclipse lead to any issues?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I've recently started learning Spring REST. As part of my learning process, I developed a simple Hello World application using Maven. The directory structure of maven offered by Eclipse doesn't contain the "
java" folder in src/main. So, I added it explicitly. It turns out the application gives me a 404 error as you can see in the below image. I'm sure this has something to do with the class path. As I'm new to maven I don't understand the concept of the classpath.

But in the second image, I created the project using "co.ntier" (maven archetype for Spring MVC).  The directory structure of this archetype has got the java folder which is why when I run the application I'm able to get the output.
How to add or configure maven so that every time I create a new maven project, the directory structure will have the java folder? Please help me.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to always create a Maven project from an archetype.

You can e.g. use the quickstart archetype for a simple project.

Comment: @Meier Thanks for the response, I did create the maven project using an archetype (web archetype ) to be specific as I created a web application. But this archetype doesn't contain the java folder which is why I added one explicitly

Answer (score 1):

The presence of a "java" folder has nothing to do with whether an application can successfully serve something at a particular url.  They are not directly related.  This also has nothing to do with the classpath.

However, the red mark on the project indicates an error, and as the DEFAULT location for compilable source in a Maven project is "src/main/java", it seems clear that the lack of the "java" folder results in the project not being deployed, which IS why you get a 404.

In short, if you have red marks in the project, it's not going to deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. On that note, how can I get rid of that annoying red mark on my project?. Adding an explicit "java" folder in "src/main" doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. Please help me, I'm new to Maven.

Comment: You'll need to examine the "Problems" view for the list of specific issues in the project. I also suggest you click on the three vertical dots menu, select "Show" and select "Errors/Warnings on Project" to avoid distractions from other projects. It's also good to click on the "Filter" icon and uncheck "use limits".  Now go to the list of issues and focus on the "Errors", the first one first.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I found a thread addressing the same issue here on Stack Overflow and I resolved the issue. It was a Maven JEE configuration error. Just like you said, the error has nothing to do with the classpath.